# Apt-get upgrade broken

Tags: sd-card, apt, update

I've got an error while trying to upgrade my pi. I can't even reboot it. My SD Card wasn't full.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils libapache2-mod-php5 libapt-inst1.5
  libapt-pkg4.12 libgme0 libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev
  libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi0 libsmbclient libtevent0 libva1
  libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-server0 libwbclient0 php5 php5-cli php5-common
  php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-readline raspberrypi-bootloader
  raspberrypi-kernel raspberrypi-sys-mods samba-common samba-libs
  va-driver-all
30 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/78,3 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 86,0 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 10.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 12.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 14.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 15.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 17.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 20.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 21.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 22.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 23.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 24.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 25.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 26.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 27.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 28.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 31.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 32.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 33.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 35.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 36.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 39.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 40.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 41.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 43.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 44.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 45.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 47.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 48.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 49.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 50.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 52.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 54.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 55.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 56.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 57.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 58.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 59.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 60.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 62.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 63.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 64.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 66.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 67.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 68.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 69.
Use of uninitialized value $item in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 85, <__ANONIO__> chunk 69.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $item in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 85, <__ANONIO__> chunk 1.
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/apt_1.0.9.8.4_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libapt-inst1.5_1.0.9.8.4_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libwbclient0_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u2_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libtevent0_0.9.28-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libsmbclient_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u2_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/samba-libs_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u2_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/samba-common_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u2_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/apt-utils_1.0.9.8.4_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.4_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-gd_5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-readline_5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-cli_5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-mcrypt_5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-mysql_5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libapache2-mod-php5_5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-common_5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libgme0_0.5.5-2+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libva1_1.7.3-2_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-cursor0_1.11.0-2_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-server0_1.11.0-2_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5_5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/raspberrypi-sys-mods_20161220_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/va-driver-all_1.7.3-2_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libraspberrypi-dev_1.20161215-1_armhf.deb
E: Signature d'archive invalide
E: Erreur interne, ne peut localiser la partie control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libraspberrypi-doc_1.20161215-1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/raspberrypi-kernel_1.20161215-1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libraspberrypi-bin_1.20161215-1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libraspberrypi0_1.20161215-1_armhf.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/raspberrypi-bootloader_1.20161215-1_armhf.deb
debconf: Échec d'apt-extracttemplates : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
dpkg : erreur fatale irréversible, abandon :
 la liste des fichiers pour le paquet « install-info » n'a pas de retour à la ligne en fin de fichier
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I really don't understand the errors, I've tried to update, to update the kernel, to apt-get clean, nothing works. I don't want to reinstall everything, it took me a while to configure all my pi. What could I do ?

Comment: Run `/usr/share/debconf/fix_db.pl` and try again.

Comment: Well it worked at first, then I did apt-get update and it seems it's broken again, even the /usr/share/debconf/fix_db.pl seems to be broken...